# some assets have volumeId set to NULL in database

Tags: assets, database

I noticed that some of my assets have `volemeId` column set to `NULL` in the database table `assets`.

Is it normal? Should I attach them manually to some volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it normal?

Yes. It's a nullable column in the database.

> Should I attach them manually to some volume?

Nope. There are many scenarios where Craft creates temporary volumes and temporary assets where they won't belong to an "official" volume.